# JSP dependency throwing an error

Tags: jsp

I am trying working on  when one bean is dependent on others.

I have wriiten following piece of code

Lion.java

```
public class Lion 

{
private String Lname;

public String getLname() 
{
return Lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname)
{
Lname = lname;
}

}
```

Zoo.java
    package com.example;

```
public class Zoo 
{
private Lion lion;
private String address; 
public Lion getLion() 
{
return lion;
}
public void setLion(Lion lion)
{
this.lion = lion;
}
public String getAddress()
{
return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) 
{
this.address = address;
}

}
```

and the jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Zoo</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="zoo" class="com.example.Zoo" scope="request" />
<jsp:setProperty name="zoo" property="address" value="bannerghatta" />
<jsp:setProperty name="zoo" property="lion" value="${lion}" />
<jsp:useBean id="lion" class="com.example.Lion" scope="request" />
<jsp:setProperty name="lion" property="Lname" value="Shera" />
</body>
</html>
```

However its throwing an error:-org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'Lname' in a bean of type 'com.example.Lion'

Can aanyone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Property reference in the JSP should be lname and not Lname.
For more info, checkout [this article](http://www.jpalace.org/docs/tutorials/jee/jsp_9.html).

For the complete reference, checkout [this PDF](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) from Sun. (section 8.8 - Capitalization of inferred names.).

Comment: i am using this to print lion name:-${zoo.lion.lname}...however its not printing anuthing however when i am using a ${zoo.address} its printing address correctly

Comment: Is there a lion in scope when calling <jsp:setProperty name="zoo" property="lion" value="${lion}" /> ?

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to change the jsp:setProperty to use lname instead of Lname (that is causing the JasperException)

Comment: i have modified the code in jsp and the jsp now looks like this

Comment: change private String Lname into private String lname. instance variables should always start with lowercase.